# Не получается вывести поле с датой в представление ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

В базе есть поле "Created_at" [Timestamp], хочу его вывести в представление:

```
@model MyMVCApp.Models.Post
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Info</h2>

<h3>@Model.Title</h3>

<p>@Model.Created</p>
<p>@Model.Description</p>
<p>Author: @Model.Author</p>
```

В модели:

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Created_at { get; set; }
public string Created
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Created_at);
    }
}
```

В итоге, вываливается ошибка:

```
Сообщение об ошибке компилятора: CS1061: 'Post' does not contain a definition for 'Created' and no extension method 'Created' accepting a first argument of type 'Post' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Ошибка источника:


Строка 9:  <h3>@Model.Title</h3>
Строка 10: 
Строка 11: <p>@Model.Created</p> //тут
Строка 12: <p>@Model.Description</p>
Строка 13: <p>Author: @Model.Author</p>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Как вывести дату и время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перевести ошибку, то получится, что Visual Studio "не видит" свойство `Created` в модели `Post`.

У вас нет ошибки, по крайнер мере в том коде, что вы прикрепили к вопросу. По опыту скажу, что Visual Studio любит "тупить" при работе с моделями во вьюхах.

Перезапустите Visual Studio или даже ПК - это должно заставить вижлу почистить свой кэш и обновить данные вашей модели. Так же можете попробовать "Clean Solution" и "Rebuild Solution", и удалите папку `.vs`.

Comment: Clean Solution пробовал, студию тоже перезагружал, не помогает)

Comment: @YuriG ПК перезагружали? В любом случае, ответ на вопрос про вывод данных я дал, всё работает. По проблемам вижлы ищите решение сами или создавайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Благодарю! Комп пока не перезагружал, после перезагрузки постараюсь отписать сюда в чем было дело.